# Why Does My 3D Printer Stop Extruding PLA?

Tags: creality-ender-3, ultimaker-cura, extrusion, underextrusion, print-failure

I have an Ender 3 V2 which is around 6 months old. Recently, extruding slowed to an almost complete halt seconds into a print for no apparent reason. The extruder works perfectly when extruding manually (using the extrude setting) and I see no reason for it to not extrude properly. I am using Ultimaker Cura  and a new filament (my old one has the same issue). The print speed is 10mm/s and the temperature is correct for the filament which is PLA+.

After some testing it seems random when it stops extruding but it always happens within the first 10 seconds of the print starting.

Comment: Since you're not printing fast or anything, I think the most likely explanation is a loose or broken tension arm on the extruder. Check that it's gripping the filament and watch what happens when it stops working.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE It can extrude manually when I turn the extrusion wheel by hand or when I use the extrude function under "move". It only stops whilst it is printing a model so I don't think it is the tension arm but I'll have a look and get back to you in a bit.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE After having a look it seems that the extruder just starts turning incredibly slowly just after starting the print (never during the line that it does at the beginning of every print).

Comment: Wait, so it only extrudes the priming line, then nothing comes out for the model? Sounds like you have your slicer configured for extremely low or no flow, or wrong filament diameter.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE It works for the 3 seconds (ish) on the actual print and then stops working. I will have a fiddle with the Slicer settings.

Comment: After changing the setting on Cura I have gotten it to extrude filaments consistently but now the filament won't stick to the build plate and sticks to the nozzle. Thanks for your help if you put your comment as an answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: I have the same issue just for PLA+ with a Dremel 3D45. I can extrude Nylon, PETG, ABS with no problem. PLA+ filament comes out when I "purge" manually the material, but when printing it stops (and clogs the extruder) after few layers. I checked the Cura settings and they seems correct: 100% flow @ 210-230 °C.

Comment: @JacobBoughton The print not sticking to the bed is probably one of the most common problems; we all run into that from time to time. I’m sure there are good questions about that here, so search around. A few easy things to check are: nozzle distance at z=0; make sure the build plate is clean, not oily at all; nozzle temperature; bed temperature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it only extrudes the priming line, then nothing comes out for the model, this sounds like you have your slicer configured for extremely low or no flow, or wrong filament diameter. Check that any flow settings are at or near 100% and that the filament diameter in the machine, extruder, **and** material settings is correct (1.75 mm for most printers).